# Why does my android API checking not work?

Tags: android, backwards-compatibility

Basically, this is what I am exactly doing:

```
if (Integer.valueOf(Build.VERSION.SDK) >= 9) {
    editor.apply();
} else {
    editor.commit();
}
```

but why it only works with API 7 or above? My app has declared to support minimum API 3, but it crashes on loading with java.lang.VerifyError, stating the apply() method cannot be found.

> This approach only works for Android 2.1 (API level 7) and above. If you support 1.6 (API level 4), the editor.apply() call will have to be wrapped in a static class. These days, very few apps have to support that old versions of Android, so I will not provide an example for this.

(reference: http://simonvt.net/2012/02/07/what-api-level-should-i-target/ )

Should I drop support for API 3 to 6 altogether for my app in this case?

Answer (score 1):

> Should I drop support for API 3 to 6 altogether for my app in this case?

You should at least drop support for API Level 3 and 4, as that will simplify your code substantially, and approximately zero people are using such devices today. Backwards compatibility for things like this got a lot simpler with Android 2.0 (API Level 5), as the stuff that you quoted is no longer needed.

Then, do not use `Build.VERSION.SDK`, let alone converting it yourself to an `Integer`. Quoting [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.VERSION.html#SDK):

> This field was deprecated in API level 4. Use [SDK_INT](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.VERSION.html#SDK_INT) to easily get this as an integer.

Answer (score 0):

You can safely set your minSdk to 9. You'll then cover most of the devices (over 99%) and save yourself a lot of trouble maintaining compatibility.

If you choose to target only 80% of devices API 16 is a safe and more comfortable option.

Source: https://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html